# http request header - some special chars removed from URI

Tags: c, http, https

I am developing a http server, planned to serve as a media server later.
In that context I extract the requested file/url from the http request header,
which was working fine so far, till I noticed that some special chars get removed from the uri.

Example: URL Browser/Client
https://domain/over/there?name=ferret#nose

Server socket receives: https://domain/over/there?name=ferret

So #nose is cut off. Same cut off happens eg on &

May this be because of wrong uri scheme or maybe an encoding issue?
I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters
but I am wondering, cos some reserved chars work, some do not.

For the client requests I used firefox 88 and chrome 90.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about `&` (it is used for separating parameters and should be included in URLs), but `#` is used for indicate the place inside the page (anchor), so it may be removed from HTTP request.

Comment: I checked anchor links with the developer tools and it really seems it gets removed from the header and only handled within the browser. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This is referred to as the `fragment` in the URI specs. It should be cut off, because it is for the client to handle. If it isn't cut off, your server should ignore that part. Oh, and a client *can* use percent-encoding for any character (even regular ones), so you should just decode them all. Reserved characters must be encoded if the character has a special meaning *in that context* So they can be sent unencoded in other contexts.